# How to pass raw JSON as a response from Restful service?

Tags: java, json, rest

I have a RestService in which I am returning a JSON response as shown below.

Below is my code:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@GET
@Path("/json/lime")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public DataResponse getData(@Context DataInfo info) {

    // some code here
    System.out.println(resp.getResponse());
    return new DataResponse(resp.getResponse());
}
```

Below is the actual JSON response I get back after hitting my Restful Service:

```
{
    "response": "{\"ABC\":100,\"PQR\":\"40\"}\n",
}
```

And this is what it gets printed out from System.out as shown above:

```
{"ABC":100,"PQR":"40"}
```

Here is my `DataResponse` class:

```
public class DataResponse {

    private String response;

    public DataResponse(String response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

    public String getResponse() {
        return this.response;
    }
}
```

As you can see, my `response` string is getting escaped in the above JSON. And I am not sure why? Can anyone help me understand why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: What is `resp` I don't see it defined anywhere?

Comment: @brso05 Does it matter here? `resp` is an object from which I get a String which has JSON response: So `resp.getResponse()` returns back a JSON response without any escaping at all. Updated the question with more details.

Comment: You need to give us more like `DataResponse` class and what is `resp.getResponse()` returning.

Comment: Just updated my question.

Comment: I just posted an answer I know what your problem is if you have any question just ask...

Answer (score 2):

Use Response class:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

    @GET
    @Path("/json/lime")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public ResponsegetData(@Context DataInfo info) {
        ...
        return Response.status(200).entity(resp.getResponse()).build();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are trying to return a `JSON` string as the response.  Let the webservice build the `JSON` for you like so (don't build the `JSON` string yourself):

```
public class DataResponse {

    private int ABC;
    private String PQR;

    public DataResponse()
    {

    }

    public DataResponse(int ABC, String PQR) {
        this.ABC = 100;
        this.PQR = "40";
    }
    //getters and setters here
}
```

The above is just an example I don't expect you to hard code values.

The resulting `JSON` of the above should be something like:

```
{
    "ABC":100,
    "PQR":"40"
}
```

The program is working as expected it is changing your `DataResponse` class into `JSON` but since you have `JSON` stored in the string that it is converting it is escaping characters in `Javascript`.

```
{
    "response": "{\"ABC\":100,\"PQR\":\"40\"}\n",
}
```

Your javascript object will be like this:

```
window.alert(data.response);
```

Should print:

```
{"ABC":100,"PQR":"40"} //same as system.out.print
```

I hope you understand what I am saying if not just ask...

***************************************************UPDATE********************************************************

```
@GET
@Path("/json/lime")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getData(@Context DataInfo info) {

    // some code here
    System.out.println(resp.getResponse());
    return resp.getResponse();
}
```

Javascript side convert `String` to `Object` example:

```
var test = JSON.parse("{\"ABC\":100,\"PQR\":\"40\"}");
window.alert(test.ABC);
window.alert(test.PQR);
```

`String` to `JSON` reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5686237/4028085)

Comment: In my case, my pojo is not general. JSON response can be in any POJO so that's why it is coming as string in DataResponse.

Comment: @david then instead of returning an `object` as `JSON` return a `String` as plain text then on the `javascript` side convert that `string` to an object...

Comment: @david since it is already in `JSON` format you don't need the web service to convert it...

Answer (score 0):

Your response contains double quotes in it. Without escaping them, the value wouldn't be parsable, for example, your string would look like "{"ABC":100,"PQR":"40"}\n", which isn't a valid string value at all. To include any character that has special meaning in a string, it has to be escaped.